# API Controller action для загрузки большого файла по частям

Tags: c#, файлы, загрузка, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

Использую в своем проекте на фронте библиотеку [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload), которая умеет передавать файл кусками по требуемому размеру (параметр `resumeChunkSize`).
Но при этом не получается написать метод контроллера что бы принять этот файл. Он вроде как Multipart должен приходить, а для работы с этим на .NET 5 не нашел никаких примеров.

Как правильно принять этот файл по кускам и склеить в один?

UPDATE

Прочитав информацию и туториалы я понял что требуется разъяснить ситуацию
Почти все статьи про загрузку файлов сводятся либо к простой загрузке (за один раз файл целиком) или к потоковой загрузке файла. Мне не подходит ни одно ни другое. По сути мне надо загрузить БОЛЬШОЙ файл, поэтому он разбивается на небольшие порции (скажем по 1мб) и каждая такая порция уже в виде отдельного запроса улетает на сервер.

Так вот по сути задача собрать файл воедино используя те кусочки что приходят в разных запросах. Ранее в ASP.NET 4.5 я использовал (точнее до меня использовали) класс `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider`. Но в .NET 5 такого класса нет. И как выкрутиться я что то не могу сообразить

Comment: Смотрите в сетевой лог браузера, как именно он передает файл, тогда сможете понять, как его принять.

Comment: @aepot передается он как несколько запросов фиксированного размера, как я и хотел, в заголовках есть такое `content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryEEIKo1XDN3k9wWce`. ранее в asp.net я сохранял через функционал 

```c#
request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
                ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(o =>{
})
```
но не нашел аналога в .net core 5, вероятно это делается легче просто я пока не нашел как